# Cannot call SQL in PHP function

Tags: php, sql, function

I'm trying to run a SQL statement in a function, but when I do so, nothing happens.

Here is my code ....

```
<?php 

$id = 47665;
function call($id)
{

$getBookTitle = $this->EE->db->query("SELECT b.title
                                      FROM books as b
                                      WHERE b.side = 'open'
                                      AND b.swarm_suit = 1
                                      AND b.book_id = ".$id. "
                                      ");

$variable;
foreach ($getBookTitle ->result_array() as $key)
{
  $variable = $key['title'];
}

echo $variable;
}

call(0254);
?>
```

If I run this SQL statement outside the function, it works perfectly.

Help, anyone?

Comment: The statement WORKS. But when I put it in a function, I dont get anything out.

Comment: @ACetin because simple copy-paste CAN'T do all work.

Comment: I wrote the code myself. Can you then tell me, what CAN do the work? You are not providing a constructive answer.

Comment: Consider putting `echo $variable` into `foreach` loop, as it will echo only last element. You also need to know what `$this` variable is.

Comment: I need to have echo $variable outside foreach loop.

Comment: The thing is, the statement _may_ work in other context, but since there is no `$this` variable on that scope, it can't even communicate with the database, so it can't work.

Comment: Oh, I see. That makes sense :-) Any ideas what i should write instead?

Answer (score 1):

Your foreach is iterating over a non existant variable.

Should it not be `foreach( $getBookTitle`

---

With regards tot he scope issues you are having. Id suggest you define a new database handle.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "database");
$mysqli->query("SELECT b.title
                                      FROM books as b
                                      WHERE b.side = 'open'
                                      AND b.swarm_suit = 1
                                      AND b.book_id = ".$id. "
                                      ");
```

Answer (score 0):

What? Undefined `$getRestaurantName` ?

He use `$this` inside a function, not in a object method!

```
<?php

$id = 47665;
function call($id)
{
    /*
     * What is $this? Where is class?
     */
    $getBookTitle = $this->EE->db->query("SELECT b.title
                                          FROM books as b
                                          WHERE b.side = 'open'
                                          AND b.swarm_suit = 1
                                          AND b.book_id = ".$id. "
                                          ");

    $variable; // Notice: undefined variable

    foreach ($getBookTitle ->result_array() as $key)
    {
      $variable = $key['title'];
    }

    echo $variable;
}
```

Seems that you're simple turned off all PHP errors and warnings.

### UPDATE

```
<?php

// Just for example
class _class {
    public $EE; // Your 'EE' definition

    private static $instance;

    public static function getInstance() {
        if(!self::$instance) self::$instance = new self();
        return self::$instance;
    }
}

function call($id)
{
    $obj = _class::getInstance(); // You should get instance of object where 'EE' defined. Use singletone pattern for this.

    $getBookTitle = $obj->EE->db->query("SELECT b.title
                                        FROM books as b
                                        WHERE b.side = 'open'
                                        AND b.swarm_suit = 1
                                        AND b.book_id = ".$id. "
                                        ");

    $variable = NULL;

    foreach ($getBookTitle ->result_array() as $key)
    {
        $variable = $key['title'];
    }

    echo $variable;
}
call(0254);
```

Comment: $this means "this scope", right? If youre using "this" in a class, it means class scope, if you use "this" in a method/function, it means "in this methods scope"